# Massive disk i/o on memory reach %70

Tags: swap

Previously system became unresponsive when RAM usage reached around %70. It was because of massive disk I/O operation, presumably to swap disk. I tried to tweak swapiness factor and it didn't affect anything at all on both sides of the extreme. I decided to delete the swap partition altogether, since my system has 4GB RAM. The swap partition was about 6GB. It is yet no difference. It seems in whatsoever configuration, %30 of memory should always be free. This is not a space rocket command and control system, so I don't understand this cautious policy. Can anyone please explain? Is there any other setting I could tweak to get the bar of memory usage up to say %95?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux uses all unused RAM for disk cache ('cached' value in `free`). As more RAM is used by applications the less RAM is available for caching disk activities. So if your system has high I/O throughput on recurring files it has to read the same files again and again when most of the RAM is used by applications which will make it unresponsive.

Comment: Lets say that's what happens!